# Asking permission to use client's name/products on a website?

Tags: legal

Are there legal agreements that clients need to use in order to mention their clients on the website?  For example, "We've done work for HBO, Amazon, Dell, etc"

Also, if your clients wanted to use products that they've created for their clients in their case studies, would they need permission for this as well?  Or, is there some sort of legal agreement they have their client sign for CYA reasons?

Answer (score 1):

Good question. I guess it depends on where you are. But in the U.S. no. If you are speaking of your experience and are factual, you do not need permission. But I would clear it anyway. Not for legal reason, but for ethical reasons such as offering them first right of perusal and input. It maybe they will be super helpful and provide a graphic to use and a URL to link to. After all, from a marketing standpoint, this is gold.

Comment: Any idea if there is a standard name for this type of legal document?

Comment: No. Not a legal document. It can be as casual as getting permission in an e-mail. I have seen this done through the marketing department more than anything.